# How can I cache a dynamic page to a flat file in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to roll a caching system to reduce the load on the database.

I want to be able to compare timestamps of the last updated time the flat file was updated 
to make sure it's not too long ago that the file was last updated.

Here's the code:

```
$cache_file = $_GET[ 'page_id' ] . '.html';

function cache() {

    // Here i want to get the timestamp of the file that was previously cached, 
    // if it exists.
    // If the file doesn't exist, create it.
    // If it does exist, check last modified time, if it's too long ago, then overwrite
    // the file.


    $ob = ob_get_contents();

    file_put_contents( $cache_file, $ob );

}

function loadFromCache( $page_id ) {
    $file_name = $page_id . '.html';
    if( ! file_exists( $file_name  ) ) {
         return false;
    }
    readfile( $file_name );
    return true;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you're just outputing the file, instead of `echo file_get_contents($file_name);` it should be faster to just `readfile($file_name);`. That will output the file content to the browser without loading the entire file in memory first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) to get the modification time for a file.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get timestamp of the last modification of the current file you can use code below:

```
<?php
    $stat = (stat(__FILE__));
    echo 'Document last updated: ', date('M d Y', $stat['mtime']);
?>
```

Comment: i don't want the current file. I want the modified time for the cache file.

Answer (score -2):

Why not use one of the php cacheing options [out there](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=php+cache&meta=)?  PHP Accelerator or PHP:APC?  These provide a ready rolled solution for what you want.

Comment: APC doesn't cache output, it caches bytecode, which is then executed.  APC's default behavior wouldn't reduce database load, which is what he requested.  You *could* use APC's user key store to store output yourself, but frankly, that's not really APC's strength.